Setup deeplink with jetpack compose
I'm trying to set up a deeplink for my Android app, but when I try to follow this deeplink in the browser, I don't get to the correct screen of my app, I only get Google search results, what am I doing wrong?
I'm testing this using an emulator.
I would appreciate any help
composable(
        route = Screens.Auth.route,
        deepLinks = listOf(
            navDeepLink {
                uriPattern = "myapp://home/profile"
                action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
            }
        )
    ) {
        ProfileScreen()
    }

and my androidManifest file look like this
<intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:host="home"
                  android:scheme="myapp"
                  android:pathPrefix="/profile"/>
</intent-filter>

